# React Native AsyncStorage | Row too big to fit into CursorWindow

Tags: sqlite, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm using `AsyncStorage` in ReactNative to store some data (large size >2MB) on device, and then read it with the following code

```
try {
   const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('date_stored_copy');
} catch (e) {
   console.log(e);
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Row too big to fit into CursorWindow requiredPos=0, totalRows=1...

Is there any way to increase CursorWindow size, or another alternative to AsyncStorage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another alternative mentioned [here](https://bhanu.io/react-native-asyncstorage-filesystem-based-alternative-4316aea3e11b)

Just install `react-native-fs-store`

```
npm i react-native-fs react-native-fs-store

react-native link react-native-fs
```

And use it like this:

```
import Store from "react-native-fs-store";
const AsyncStorage = new Store('store1');
```

it has has exactly same API as that of AsyncStorage, so no code changes are required

** Please notice that `react-native-fs-store` is slower than `AsyncStorage`, as each operation is synced to file. So you may notice lag (unresponsive screen) while reading/writing data

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution would be to split the data into chunks and then write it.

I wrote [a wrapper that uses `AsyncStorage`](https://gist.github.com/bureyburey/2345dfa88a31e00a514479be37848d42) that does exactly that.

Be aware that it was originally written for using with apollo-cache-persist (a persistence lib for apollo-client).
And since GraphQL stores the data in a very flat structure this solution works pretty well out of the box.

For your case, if your stored object looks like this:

```json
{
    data: { a lot of data here }
}
```

Then it wouldn't matter much and the wrapper won't work.

But if your object looks like this:

```json
{
    someData: { partial data },
    someMoreData: { more partial data },
    ....
}
```

Then in theory it should work.

Full disclosure: I haven't tested it thoroughly yet and only used it with apollo-cache-persist.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem too, here is how I solved this issue :

Basic description of the algorithm :

- The "key" holds the number of parts your data will be divided by. (Example : key is "MyElementToStore", its value is 7 for the number of parts your data needs to be split by to fit each part in a row of the AsyncStorage)
- Each part will then be stored as an individual row in the AsyncStorage by having the name of the key followed by the index of the part. (Example : ["MyElementToStore0", "MyElementToStore1", ...]
- Retrieving data works the other way around, each row is retrieved and aggregated to the result to return
- Final note for clearing the store, it's important to remove each part before removing the key (use the last function "clearStore" to make sure you release memory correctly)

[AsyncStorage documentation](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/)

```js
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

const getStore = async (key) =>
{
  try
  {
    let store = "";
    let numberOfParts = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    if(typeof(numberOfParts) === 'undefined' || numberOfParts === null)
      return null;
    else
      numberOfParts = parseInt(numberOfParts);
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfParts; i++) { store += await AsyncStorage.getItem(key + i); }
    if(store === "")
      return null;
    return JSON.parse(store);
  }
  catch (error)
  {
    console.log("Could not get [" + key + "] from store.");
    console.log(error);
    return null;
  }
};

const saveStore = async (key, data) =>
{
  try
  {
    const store = JSON.stringify(data).match(/.{1,1000000}/g);
    store.forEach((part, index) => { AsyncStorage.setItem((key + index), part); });
    AsyncStorage.setItem(key, ("" + store.length));
  }
  catch (error)
  {
    console.log("Could not save store : ");
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};

const clearStore = async (key) =>
{
  try
  {
    console.log("Clearing store for [" + key + "]");
    let numberOfParts = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    if(typeof(numberOfParts) !== 'undefined' && numberOfParts !== null)
    {
      numberOfParts = parseInt(numberOfParts);
      for (let i = 0; i < numberOfParts; i++) { AsyncStorage.removeItem(key + i); }
      AsyncStorage.removeItem(key);
    }
  }
  catch (error)
  {
    console.log("Could not clear store : ");
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

**android/app/src/main/java/com/tamotam/mainApp/MainApplication.java**

```java
import android.database.CursorWindow;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
...
@Override
public void onCreate() {
...
  try {
    Field field = CursorWindow.class.getDeclaredField("sCursorWindowSize");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.set(null, 100 * 1024 * 1024); // the 100MB is the new size
   } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Fixed the issue for me, remember to include the 2 imports!

As per https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage/issues/364#issuecomment-665800433 there might be an addition check `if (DEBUG_MODE)...` in some solutions, but it caused `Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.` in my case.

Answer (score 1):

AsyncStorage for Android uses SQLite for storage backend. While it has its own size limits, Android system also have two known limits: total storage size and per-entry size limit.

Total storage size is capped at 6 MB by default. You can increase this size by specifying a new size using feature flag.

Per-entry is limited by a size of a WindowCursor, a buffer used to read data from SQLite. Currently it's size is around 2 MB. This means that the single item read at one time cannot be larger than 2 MB. There's no supported workaround from AsyncStorage. We suggest keeping your data lower than that, by chopping it down into many entries, instead of one massive entry. This is where multiGet and multiSet APIs can shine